# Autolayout cell height not working for single cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I've been using autolayout to determine `heightForRowAtIndexPath` within one of my tables. It works for all of my cells except one. Any ideas what I should be looking for to resolve the problem?

It's the `HILargeMessageImageCell` which is not returning the height properly. Right now it returns 0. Here's the code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell;
    if( indexPath.row == 0 )
    {
        if( self.message.image )
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HILargeMessageImageCell"];
            [(HILargeMessageImageCell *)cell initWithMessage:self.message];
        }else{
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HILargeMessageCell"];
            [(HILargeMessageCell *)cell initWithMessage:self.message];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HIChildMessageCell"];
        [(HIChildMessageCell *)cell initWithMessage:[self.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]];
    }
    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    NSLog(@"HEight is: %f",height);
    return height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0 for the cell spacer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to say without seeing all of your code, but here is an excellent example of using autolayout on custom cells.

The post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

The github sample code - https://github.com/caoimghgin/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout

Here the author suggests calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` first, like this:

```
// Make sure the constraints have been added to this cell, since it may have just been created from scratch
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

// Set the width of the cell to match the width of the table view. This is important so that we'll get the
// correct height for different table view widths, since our cell's height depends on its width due to
// the multi-line UILabel word wrapping. Don't need to do this above in -[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath]
// because it happens automatically when the cell is used in the table view.
cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

// Do the layout pass on the cell, which will calculate the frames for all the views based on the constraints
// (Note that the preferredMaxLayoutWidth is set on multi-line UILabels inside the -[layoutSubviews] method
// in the UITableViewCell subclass
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];

// Get the actual height required for the cell
CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

// Add an extra point to the height to account for the cell separator, which is added between the bottom
// of the cell's contentView and the bottom of the table view cell.
height += 1;

return height;
```

Edit: Another thought - a hight of 0 can often mean a problem with your constraints.  In some cases you constraints can only be satisfied with a height of zero. Did you do this programmatically or in IB?  Can you share you constraints for `HILargeMessageImageCell`?

Comment: I did the constraints within interface builder

Comment: I deleted the cell and redid it and everything worked again. Who knows what happened!

Comment: I'm willing to bet your constraints got messed up in IB and your cell height actually was 0.